# Any Workaround for error: ISO C++ does not allow C99 designated initializers [-Wpedantic]

Tags: c++11, g++

Is there any workaround for this error except replacing all the structure instantiations by ":" instead of "=". I am using G++.

Comment: Yes there is a workaround, to *not* use something that's not part of C++. Remember that C and C++ are two very different languages.

Comment: yes, but I need to use g++. I have both c and cpp files in my project. I used g++ -x c, it worked now. But any idea g++ -x c would lead to any further errors?

Comment: Keep the C-specific code to the C source files, and the C++-specific code to the C++ source files. And don't put language-specific things in header files without protection (with e.g. `#ifdef __cplusplus` or similar). Build the C source files with the `gcc` frontend, the C++ source files with the `g++` frontend. And link with `g++`. That's it.